# Codecov: gcov code coverage for a C++ library

Tags: c++, code-coverage, static-libraries, gcov

I am writting a small C++ static library. Within GitHub Actions I have a "unit test" workflow which compiles and runs a test program and the code coverage is submitted to the *Codecov* service afterwards. It runs: `g++ test.cpp library/library.cpp --coverage -o test`, then `./test`, followed by `gcov -o . test.cpp`. In the next step the results are submitted to my *Codecov* account with a standard `bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)` (having a `CODECOV_TOKEN` set as an env. variable). Everything works fine up to this point.

However, in the coverage I see reports for both `.cpp` and `.h` files inslide the library directory but also a coverage of the `test.cpp`. I am not interested in the coverage of my test code and it is skewing the statistics. Is there any way to submit only coverage reports of the library files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to exclude files at the `gcov` level, but I solved the issue by restricting the `codecov` submission: https://docs.codecov.io/docs/ignoring-paths